# Email validation for Mat-chip-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to apply email validation to mat-chip. Below is my attempt to achieve the same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chip-demo-yvmxsk

My requirement is to display an mat-error when user enters an invalid email ID and highlight only invalid email ID. Can someone help me on the same?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight

Comment: Highlight as in only invalid entry should be displayed in some color like red.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a property on the added email value such as invalid.

```
add(event): void {
    console.log(event.value)
    if (event.value) {
      if (this.validateEmail(event.value)) {
        this.emailList.push({value:event.value, invalid:false});
      }else{
        this.emailList.push({value:event.value, invalid:true}); 
      }
    }
    if (event.input) {
      event.input.value = '';
    }
}
```

then, you can highlight the chip by dynamically setting the color:

```
<mat-chip [color]="(item.invalid)?'warn':''" selected />
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chip-demo-dhm17z)

For more info about chips:
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

FYI, I used a simple email validator using regex:

```
private validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This is indeed helpful for highlighting invalid entry however this solution is not setting up a control to invalid, due to which mat-error is not triggering. Can you suggest any way to achieve that?

Comment: All you have to do is to add the error state to the form inside the `add` method. Then, you can show `mat-error` based on the existence of the error state. Please see my updated stackblitz

Comment: @umutesen   i have a question please, how to improve your could so that : while there are invalid emails in the chip list then that error message should be appears, otherwise not

Comment: please help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583859/how-to-change-the-error-message-in-mat-chip-dinamecally