# How to change the error message in mat-chip dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I have this demo in stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chip-demo-dhm17z

It checks for email validation, but there is a bug in the code in the `error message` ***"Invalid email ID
"*** , the error message appears also if there is no invalid emails in the listing after removing the invalid emails.

how can i fix it, so that:

While there is an invalid chip element in the listing => error message should appear
if there is only valid emials in the listing => error message should not be appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `component.ts` add:

```js
areEmailsInvalid(): boolean {
  return this.emailList.some(email => !this.validateEmail(email.value));
}
```

and remove the invalid thing from else:

```js
else {
  this.emailList.push({ value: event.value, invalid: true });
}
```

Also in `component.html` change this:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="rulesForm.get('emails').hasError('incorrectEmail')">Invalid email ID</mat-error>
```

into this:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="areEmailsInvalid()">Invalid email ID</mat-error>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have last question please, how can i make it possible that [color] takes its value from css and not directly defined in html. e.g. `[color]="(item.invalid)?'CSS color warn':' CSS color blue'"`

Comment: Please open a new question for this issue. What you are trying to achieve is to change `mat-chip`'s color, which is not recommended.